# Why does the compiler complain about an unused variable in this instance (when it is used by fmt.Fprintf)?

Tags: go

I have a simple piece of code where I want to convert elements of a slice into json and then print them out to my http.responseWriter.

```
for _, element := range customers {
    result, _ := json.Marshal(element)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(result))
}
```

However when I compile this I get the error "result declared and not used". If I add a simple line:

```
_ = result
```

Then everything compiles and works fine. Why does the compiler complain about this usage, and what is the correct way to do this in go?

Any insight is appreciated, my searches so far seem to indicate the call to Fprintf should count as a usage.

Comment: The code you posted does not result in the error you get. For proof, see: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oYB3JnfYHZ4). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Most likely you have a `result` variable outside of the `for` loop, and since you use  short variable declaration, that shadows the outer `result`, and most likely the outer `result` is the one that is never used, like in this example: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_SejIKP8Nzc).

Comment: Thanks @icza, that was it exactly. I didn't clock how variable declaration was working in go and it was the variable declared outside the scope that was causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: `go vet` will catch this sort of problem.

Comment: That's an awesome tip, thanks Michael

Comment: Don't use a JSON document as a format string. That's going to bite you sooner or later. Use `fmt.Fprint` (no f), or simply `w.Write(result)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question does not result in the error posted, for proof, check it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oYB3JnfYHZ4).

This error usually is (and the op confirmed it is too in this case) caused by having a local variable with same name outside of the block, and when using the [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), that shadows that variable.

This error can be reproduced with the following code:

```
var result []byte

customers := []int{}
w := os.Stdout

for _, element := range customers {
    result, _ := json.Marshal(element)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(result))
}
```

Attempting to compile and run it, we get the error (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_SejIKP8Nzc)):

```
prog.go:10:6: result declared and not used
```

Solution is to use a simple [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) instead of the short variable declaration if intention is to use the existing variable (in which case no new variable will be created), or use a different name for the variable if intention is not to use the outer, existing variable (but then the outer variable is to be removed or be used of course).